# How to create PGP-signed textfiles using Kleopatra GUI for Gpg4win that include the message en clair before the signature?

Tags: pgp, gpg4win, kleopatra

I am using Gpg4win with the Kleopatra GUI on Windows 10 Pro. When I use my private key to sign a textfile the program produces a signed textfile that authenticates properly using my public key. But for some reason all that the signed textfile contains is the signature, sandwiched between

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

and

```
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

but not preceded with the message en clair.

How can I use this program and GUI to create a signed textfile that is in what I thought was the standard format for such files, and that would look for example like this:

```
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----

Hello world!

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: [...]

[...]

-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----
```

I have looked under `Settings | Configure Kleopatra` but cannot find a toggle for this. In any case, surely the standard meaning of "sign" is "postpend a signature", so I am not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: The 'BEGIN/END PGP SIGNATURE' is actually a PGP signed _message_ and includes both the data and the signature(s); you can see this with `gpg --list-packets $file`. This is the 'normal' case for `gpg`, and I think you're right the _only_ option in Kleo. You can override in `gpg` with `--clearsign` but you didn't ask for that.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 - Thanks. That's a shame Kleo can't clearsign a .txt file. But at least it allows the clearsigning of a message using the clipboard, and I checked with a 200,000 word chunk of text so any length limit is extremely high.